# MetaPython: Adding Methods to a Class

Tags: python, binding, metaprogramming

I would like to add some methods to a class definition at runtime.  However, when running the following code, I get some surprising (to me) results.

#### test.py

```
class klass(object):
    pass

for i in [1,2]:
    def f(self):
        print(i)
    setattr(klass, 'f' + str(i), f)
```

I get the following when testing on the command line:

```
>>> import test
>>> k = test.klass()
>>> k.f1()
2
>>> k.f2()
2
```

Why does `k.f1()` return 2 instead of 1?  It seems rather counter intuitive to me.

#### notes

This test was done using python3.0 on a kubuntu machine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the usual problem of binding -- you want early binding for the use of `i` inside the function and Python is doing late binding for it.  You can force the earlier binding this way:

```
class klass(object):
    pass

for i in [1,2]:
    def f(self, i=i):
        print(i)
    setattr(klass, 'f' + str(i), f)
```

or by wrapping f into an outer function layer taking i as an argument:

```
class klass(object):
    pass

def fmaker(i):
    def f(self):
        print(i)
    return f

for i in [1,2]:
    setattr(klass, 'f' + str(i), fmaker(i))
```

Comment: Great answer, that definitely solved my problem.  Is there somewhere I can go to find the specifics on late vs. early binding?  This isn't something I've looked into before.

Comment: Good answer, I actually ask something similar when I'm interviewing people

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's because `print (i)` prints `i` not *by value*, but *by reference*. Thus, when leaving the for loop, *i* has the value **2**, which will be printed both times.

Comment: I think it's clearer to focus on early vs late binding, as I did in my answer, rather than on "by value" vs "by reference". Both of the solutions I gave are still by reference (can't be otherwise in Python;-) but the way they solve the problem is by forcing an earlier binding of the identifier in either of two ways.